# Configuring apache-camel route to external URL with JavaDSL

Tags: rest, http, spring-boot, proxy, apache-camel

I'm developing 'proxy' service using apache-camel.

### There is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.comapany</groupId>
    <artifactId>proxy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Fabric8 :: Quickstarts :: Spring-Boot :: Camel</name>
    <description>Spring Boot example running a Camel route</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- configure the versions you want to use here -->
        <fabric8.version>3.0.11.fuse-000039-redhat-1</fabric8.version>
        <spring-boot.version>1.5.12.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>

        <arquillian-cube.version>1.9.0</arquillian-cube.version>
        <assertj.version>2.4.1</assertj.version>

        <!-- maven plugin versions -->
        <fabric8.maven.plugin.version>3.5.33.fuse-000067-redhat-1</fabric8.maven.plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.19.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>fabric8-project-bom-camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
                <version>${fabric8.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Enabling health checks -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.arquillian.cube</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-cube-openshift</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>kubernetes-assertions</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-DenableImageStreamDetection=true</argLine>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*KT.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${fabric8.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resource</goal>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

there is my Application.java:

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean camelServletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CamelHttpTransportServlet(), "/proxy/*");
        registration.setName("CamelServlet");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

---

and there is my routing component:

---

```
@Component
public class Router extends RouteBuilder {

    @Value("${remote.base.url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().component("servlet").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

        rest()
            .get("/users/{id}")
            .to("direct:user_id/${header.id}");

        from("direct:user_id/${header.id}")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "request for users/id has been received")
            .toD(baseUrl + "/redirect/${header.id}/?bridgeEndpoint=true")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class);
    }
}
```

---

Basically what I'm trying to achive: stand rest endpoint, log received request, redirect it to external url.

### When I'm testing it with postman I got this:

```
org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://localhost:8090/redirect/M70%20KEP/users/M70%20KEP with statusCode: 404
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException(HttpProducer.java:273)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:182)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor$1.doInAsyncProducer(SendDynamicProcessor.java:132)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:445)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:127)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectBlockingProducer.process(DirectBlockingProducer.java:53)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:208)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:78)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:330)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

I would be extremenly thankful if someone would explain why my intended url is appended with my rest mapping?

As well if there is an example of case I'm trying to achieve - pointing to right blog or github/gitlab/bitbucket repo would be greatly apprecited.

Thansks

Comment: This is purpose of `bridgeEndpoint` option. It gets path from URL of input service and appends it to URL of output service. I beleive you dont need this option with your current implementation.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the reply. When i remove bridgingEndpoint=true I receive this exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri: /proxy/users/M70%20KEP/users/M70%20KEP. If you are forwarding/bridging http endpoints, then enable the bridgeEndpoint option on the endpoint: http://localhost:8090/redirect/M70%20KEP (exception cropped). Any ideas how to overcome this one? Thanks!

Comment: I would try to remove Camel HTTP related headers before calling target service with`.removeHeaders("CamelHttp*").toD(baseUrl..`. This should  prevent this exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that helped. I was wondering if you could help a bit further - it does look like other headers I pass are ignored. For example I set Content-Type and Accept as 'application/json' and I receive org.apache.camel.processor.binding.BindingException: Cannot bind to json as message body is not json compatible. Any advices? Would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To finalize this camel setup (and make life easier for other developers who come across the same issue).

Thanks to [@Bedla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8576169/bedla) for help with bridge endpoint - I wouldn't guess it without your help.

To overcome BindingException I had to add another dependency into pom file (but the error message in original exception doesn't help at all)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But it is not the end of the story. It happens that after removing HttpCamel headers you also remove CamelHttpMethod header, and after some time debugging I found this in code: HttpHelper -> createMethod:

```
    // compute what method to use either GET or POST (header take precedence)
    HttpMethods m = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethods.class);
    if (m != null) {
        // always use what end-user provides in a header
        answer = m;
    } else if (queryString != null) {
        // if a query string is provided then use GET
        answer = HttpMethods.GET;
    } else {
        // fallback to POST if we have payload, otherwise GET
        answer = hasPayload ? HttpMethods.POST : HttpMethods.GET;
    }
}
```

So, unless you have a query string that automatically you will be using POST (which was an issue in my case).

At the end I end up with this routing configuration:

```
@Component
public class EmailRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Value("${remote.base.url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().component("servlet").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

        rest()
            .get("/users/{id}")
            .to("direct:user_id");

        from("direct:user_id")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "request for users/id has been received")
            .removeHeaders("CamelHttp*")
            .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("GET"))
            .toD(baseUrl + "/redirect/${header.id}")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of removing all the headers just remove "CamelHttpPath" which should resolve your problem.
.removeHeader("CamelHttpPath")

Comment: Thanks, I would try, but since Camel added about 10 extra own "CamelHttp*" headers it's not easy to know which one is causing the problem.